# Workbox service worker: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, workbox

I am creating a React App using the Create React App utility and I want to override the default service worker that it provides.

Since I don't want to eject my app, I am using the `workbox-build` package to create my service worker (I also used yarn to install the `workbox-sw` package).

My service worker code is the following:

```
/* eslint-disable no-restricted-globals */
import * as core from 'workbox-core';
import * as routing from 'workbox-routing';
import * as strategies from 'workbox-strategies';
import * as precaching from 'workbox-precaching';

self.addEventListener('message', event => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});

core.clientsClaim();

routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('^https://fonts.googleapis.com'),
  new strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'google-fonts-stylesheets-v1',
  })
);

precaching.precacheAndRoute([]);

routing.registerNavigationRoute(
  precaching.getCacheKeyForURL('/index.html'), {
    blacklist: [/^\/_/, /\/[^/?]+\.[^/]+$/],
  }
);
```

And my `workbox-build` script is:

```
const workboxBuild = require('workbox-build');

// NOTE: This should be run *AFTER* all your assets are built
const buildSW = () => {
  // This will return a Promise
  return workboxBuild.injectManifest({
    swSrc: 'src/service-worker.js',
    swDest: 'build/service-worker.js',
    globDirectory: 'build',
    globPatterns: [
      '**\/*.{js,css,html,png,json}',
    ]
  }).then(({
    count,
    size,
    warnings
  }) => {
    // Optionally, log any warnings and details.
    warnings.forEach(console.warn);
    console.log(`${count} files will be precached, totaling ${size} bytes.`);
  });
}

buildSW();
```

For registering the service worker I am using:

```
import { Workbox } from 'workbox-window';

export function register() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    const wb = new Workbox('/service-worker.js');
    wb.register();
  }
}
```

However when I run my App I get these errors:

```
service-worker.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
:3000/107/aggregator:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:3000/') with script ('http://localhost:3000/service-worker.js'): ServiceWorker script evaluation failed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

### Current Answer

According to [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#browser_compatibility) it should work now, but keep an eye on the up-to-date [implementation status](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_statements_import_worker_support) in each browser. Firefox <strike>and Opera (implemented since Version 67)</strike> are still behind.

Mozilla is going to implement that feature in **Firefox 114**.

---

### Original answer from 2020

There is no module support in workers yet.

**importScripts()** could do the job for you, but it can not import modules, meaning anything with an *"export"* keyword inside.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts

Comment: This means that the best solution is probably to compile that service worker, then move the *compiled* version into `/public`.

Answer (score 2):

[fips' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60865512/1992129) helped me get on the right track.

I am not using a bundler/compiler. A bundler/compiler seems like a the avenue to pursue.

However, for anyone else that this may help:

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/6.5.3/workbox-sw.js');

workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);
```

fits well to those trying to solve some examples from [Googles documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/precaching-with-workbox/)

or more specific to your code, all those modules are accessible as attributes on the `workbox` object.

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/6.5.3/workbox-sw.js');

self.addEventListener('message', event => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});

workbox.core.clientsClaim();

workbox.routing.registerRoute(/* your params here */);

workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(/* your params here */);

// presuming OP function is deprecated in current version and changed
// to 'registerRoute', but may actually be 'NavigationRoute' check
// current documentation for more clarity.
workbox.routing.registerRoute(/* your params here */);
```