# "Cannot use import statement outside module" when registering service worker from script type=module

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, web-extension

> I've searched for existing answers regarding extensions and service workers, like [Workbox service worker: Cannot use import statement outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59272083/workbox-service-worker-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module) and the answers are either vague "it should theoretically work now" hence asking here, with a minimal example.

I am developing a Chrome extension, and **the extension, including its manifest, currently works**.

However when I add the following to `service-worker.js`

```
import { log } from "./service-worker-helpers.js";
```

...where `service-worker-helpers.js` is just:

```
export const log = console.log.bind(console);
```

I see the following behaviour:

- Loading the extension parses the service worker, run the Install event. etc, with zero errors reported on the console.
- Clicking the popup (which registers the service worker) fails with:

`Cannot use import statement outside a module`

[image]

**I understand the error - Chrome wants me to be using an ES6 module to use `import`**

However the popup itself is using `script type="module"`:

```
<script type="module" src="/assets/index.07165314.js"></script>
```

I am also using ES6 modules for my service worker - which is why loading the module (which seems to parse the service worker file) works:

```
"background": {
  "service_worker": "service-worker.js",
  "type": "module"
},
```

**How can I register a background script that uses ES6 modules?**

Comment: [A little old, but possibly of interest](https://web.dev/es-modules-in-sw/)

Comment: @Pointy Thanks, and it's a great resource, sadly I've already read it and followed it's advice before writing this question.